# Setting up GCS for webGL clients to connect through SSL

Tags: unity-game-engine, ssl, unity3d-mirror

I've been having a lot of problem to make my target setup work: hosting a headless server on GoogleCloudService, that webGL clients hosted on a platform like itch.io could connect to. I'm using Mirror and its SimpleWebTransport for connecting.

The server runs fine, and I can connect from my local server browser when SimpleWebTransport's "use WSS" and "use SSL" bools are off.

When uploading the build and running the client through itch.io tho, it's giving an error saying it needs to use WSS to connect.So I re-uploaded everything with the WSS and SSL options ticked on the SimpleWebTransport. I've also followed a guide to activate a load balancer and make an instance group so I could have a google-managed SSL certificate produced.

Now trying to connect this way gives me a new error (cf attachement).
[image]
What could I be missing setup wise? I see in the SimpleWebtransport there's a field for a path to the certificate, should I be using it and how? I do see the following error in my server's console:

FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/home/saturn_slides_gmail_com/cert.json"

Also, is it ok that i'm using port 7778 in Mirrors' setup as well as in GCS's instance group settings? Or should i be using some other ports.
thank you !